# How to use a @FetchRequest with the new searchable modifier in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, searchable, fetchrequest

Is it possible to use the new `.searchable` in combination with `@FetchRequest`?

I have a code like this:

```
struct FooListView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Foo.name, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Foo>

    @State var searchText = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: FooView(Foo: item)) {
                        Text(item.wrappedName)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .searchable(text: $searchText)
            .navigationTitle("Foos")
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to use the `searchText` to filter my `FetchedResults`.

Comment: [wwdc 2021 Core Data Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10017) about minute 21:33

Comment: searchable is a view modifier for NavigationView. What do you mean by using it for FetchResults? You can use the text as an NSPredicate.

Comment: @loremipsum this was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I'm glad it worked I added a solution

Comment: I noticed with both answers if ContentView is init again (because of a state change in a parent) the search predicate is lost even if search is still active and the full list is shown again despite there still being active search text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WWDC 2021 Bring Core Data Concurrency to Swift and SwiftUI has a great example of this right around minute 21:33

https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10017

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\Quake.time, order: .reverse)])
    private var quakes: FetchedResults<Quake>

    @State private var searchText = ""
    var query: Binding<String> {
        Binding {
            searchText
        } set: { newValue in
            searchText = newValue
            quakes.nsPredicate = newValue.isEmpty
                           ? nil
                           : NSPredicate(format: "place CONTAINS %@", newValue)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        List(quakes) { quake in
            QuakeRow(quake: quake)
        }
        .searchable(text: query)
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this approach the predicate is lost whenever the view reloads. So you end up with the searchText filled out with something but the results not reflecting that.

Answer (score 20):

I would not overcomplicate it with additional bindings. Why not only to use the onChange modifier on the searchText.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\Quake.time, order: .reverse)])
    private var quakes: FetchedResults<Quake>
    
    @State private var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        List(quakes) { quake in
            QuakeRow(quake: quake)
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText)
        .onChange(of: searchText) { newValue in
            quakes.nsPredicate = newValue.isEmpty ? nil : NSPredicate(format: "place CONTAINS %@", newValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just an addition to anyone that may not know. Within the string format, "place" represents the attribute you're wanting to search through. My app kept crashing and I couldn't figure out why. So say you've named your attribute "name". You'd write "name CONTAINS %@"

Answer (score 2):

In the other answers the predicate is lost if the `View` is re-init, e.g. by a parent `View`'s `body`. That can be fixed by putting the predicate in an `@State` (in the same struct because the searchText and predicate are related) in a parent `View` like this:

```
struct ContentViewConfig {
    var searchText = "" {
        didSet {
            predicate = searchText.isEmpty ? nil : NSPredicate(format: "place CONTAINS %@", searchText)
        }
    }
    var predicate: NSPredicate?
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var config = ContentViewConfig()

     var body: some View {
        QuakesView(predicate: config.predicate)
        .searchable(text: $config.searchText)
    }
}

struct QuakesView: View {
    static var sortDescriptors = [SortDescriptor(\Quake.time, order: .reverse)]
    
    private var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Quake>
    private var quakes: FetchedResults<Quake> {
        fetchRequest.wrappedValue
    }

    init(predicate: NSPredicate?) {
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: Self.sortDescriptors, predicate: predicate)
    }

    var body: some View {
        List(quakes) { quake in
            QuakeRow(quake: quake)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am encountering this same issue with the predicate being reset. As I understood it the whole purpose of the .nsPredicate property was so that you could dynamically update the predicate, but seems you can't do this with it constantly resetting anyway. Very frustrating.